# Como validar telefone em php

Tags: php, html

Estou tentando validar o número do telefone, tanto telefone fixo quanto celular, e estou tentando fazer assim, não importa como o usuário escrever:

11965453789

(11)965453789

(11) 965453789

(11) 96545-3789

Sempre vai salvar no banco de dados e mostrar de volta para o usuário nesse formato: (11)965453789.

Como faço isso em php?

Comment: Normalmente eu coloco apenas uma mascara, assim o usuário é forçado a digitar apenas números e no formato que preciso... http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Eu utilizo esta função para validar telefone:

```
function celular($telefone){
    $telefone= trim(str_replace('/', '', str_replace(' ', '', str_replace('-', '', str_replace(')', '', str_replace('(', '', $telefone))))));

    $regexTelefone = "^[0-9]{11}$";

    //$regexCel = '/[0-9]{2}[6789][0-9]{3,4}[0-9]{4}/'; // Regex para validar somente celular
    if (preg_match($regexCel, $telefone)) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Boa abordagem ignorar os `()-`. Podias ter no final somente `return !!preg_match($regexCel, $telefone);` e evitavas o if/else. De qq maneira `+1`.

Comment: Obrigado vou testar aqui

Comment: É mesmo @Sergio é porque antes eu tinha uns códigos dentro do if, mas eu poderia ter só retornado o preg_match.

Answer (score 8):

Acho que precisas uma regex assim: `/\(?\d{2}\)?\s?\d{5}\-?\d{4}/`

**Exemplo: https://regex101.com/r/hB8dH7/1**

Nessa regex:

- `\` é para escapar alguns caracteres especiais que sem esse `\` têm outra funcionalidade. Escapados com `\` são o caractere mesmo.
- `?` quere dizer opcional, pode haver ou não.
- `{n}` quer dizer "o caractere anterior" exatamente *n* vezes.

Podes ainda usar `^` no inicio e `$` no final para garantir que não há nada resp. antes nem depois. Nesse caso a regex seria `/^\(?\d{2}\)?\s?\d{5}\-?\d{4}$/`.

Para aplicar essa regex no PHP podes fazer assim:

```
if(preg_match("/\(?\d{2}\)?\s?\d{5}\-?\d{4}/", $phone)) {
  // o telefone é válido
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Caso queira deixar o usuário entrar com o número livremente e aplicar sanitização:

```
// número que o usuário digitou
$n = '(11) 456-456-4567';

// faz um cast para o tipo numérico inteiro.
// isso quer dizer que tudo que não for numérico, incluindo pontos, será removido.
$n = (int)$n;

//mostra resultado da sanitização
echo $n;
//output 114564564567
```

Feito isso, basta salvar no banco de dados ou qualquer outro local que desejar.

No momento de exibir poderá aplicar alguma máscara, de preferência, usando JavaScript.

## Validação

Quanto a validação, pode verificar pelo tamanho da string.

Isso vai depender também de como recebe os dados. Por exemplo, se recebe o código de área separado do número, já facilita um pouco a validação.

Celulares tem 11 dígitos, normalmente. Então uma validação poderia ser feita assim

```
if (strlen($n) == 11) {
    // provavelmente é número mobile
}
```

## Máscara

Exemplo de máscara geńerica em PHP
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/82687/4793

Exemplo de máscara genérica em JavaScript
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55235/4793

Particularmente prefiro dessa forma mais livre pois o usuário fica irritado com máscaras e validações que não toleram entrada de dados com sanitização.

## Auto formatar enquanto digita

As máscaras, especialmente, quando aplicadas em runtime, auto formatando no momento em que digita, muitas vezes acaba por atrapalhar a experiência de uso do site pelo usuário. Pior ainda quando a máscara apresenta algum bug que impeça o usuário de completar um formulário e isso é muito comum. em muitos sites.

## Vantagem

A solução proposta acima visa o reaproveitamento de códigos.

O assunto aqui é específico sobre números de telefone, porém, pode aplicar essa mesma rotina para diversos outros tipos como CEP, CPF, CNPJ, números seriais, enfim, qualquer tipo de número com qualquer tipo de formatação.

Answer (score 1):

Depois de ter consultado esta página e ter começado a rascunhar uma gambiarra, reparei que eu tinha no "baú" uma função pronta... E olhando acima reparo que o fundamento já foi dado aqui pelo @DanielOmine, lembrando que celular com DDD tem 11 dígitos e fixo 10 dígitios. PS: sem DDD são 9 e 8 respectivamente.

Foi mais ou menos no ano 2000 que os telefones brasileiros passaram a ter 8 dígitos, e entre 2010 e 2013 que todos os celulares passaram a ter 9 dígitos. Ver [normas Anatel](http://www.anatel.gov.br/Portal/exibirPortalPaginaEspecial.do?org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TOKEN=9594e1d11fbc996d52bda44e608bb744&codItemCanal=1794&pastaSelecionada=2984).

O algoritmo genérico de interpretação de uma suposta string de telefone expressa em texto livre se baseia na norma Anatel... Só é um pouco mais complicado porque precisa conferir contexto e saber diferenciar casos com e sem DDI e DDD.

---

A quem possa interessar... Algoritmo que "sanitiza" dados telefônicos digitados, escrita (em PL/SQL) e validada anos atrás... Atualizo se achar algo melhor mais tarde (deixando desde já em Wiki para você editar).

```sql
CREATE or replace FUNCTION lib.get_string_tel(text) RETURNS text AS $f$
  SELECT regexp_replace(
      $1
      ,'^.*?((\+?55[\s-]|\+\d\d[\s-])?\s*\(?\d\d\)?[\s\-\.]*\d[\.\s]?\d\d[\d\s\.\-]+).*?$'
      ,'\1'
    )
$f$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

```sql
CREATE or replace FUNCTION lib.telbr_split(
  p_tel text  -- a string contendo o telefone 
  ,p_pode_ddi boolean DEFAULT true -- deixa preceder 55?
  ,p_ddd_default text DEFAULT '11' -- contexto Sampa
  ,p_max int DEFAULT 21  -- tamaho  máximo da string para remover outros dígitos
) RETURNS text[] AS $f$
DECLARE
  basenum text;
  digits text;
  len int;
  ret text[];
BEGIN
  basenum := trim(p_tel);
  IF length(basenum)>p_max THEN
    basenum := lib.get_string_tel(basenum);
  END IF;
  digits := lib.digits(basenum);
  IF p_pode_ddi THEN
    IF length(digits)>=14 THEN
      basenum := regexp_replace(basenum,'^[^\d]*\d\d','');
      digits := lib.digits(basenum);
    ELSEIF length(digits)>=12 AND substr(digits,1,2)='55' THEN
      basenum := regexp_replace(basenum,'^[^\d]*55','');
      digits := lib.digits(basenum);
    END IF;
  END IF;
  digits := regexp_replace(digits,'^0+','');
  len := length(digits);
  IF len<=9 THEN
    digits := p_ddd_default||digits;
  END IF;
  RETURN array[substr(digits,1,2), substr(digits,3)];
END
$f$ LANGUAGE PLpgSQL IMMUTABLE;
```

A primeira função faz extração da string contendo aparentemente um número de telefone no meio de texto livre. 
Por exemplo outro dia cadastraram `Iphone 6s plus (11) 9 1234-5678` como número de telefone um daqueles formulários do Google.

A segunda é que de fato normaliza e explode o número duas partes, DDD e número.

A linguagem PL/SQL (bases PostgreSQL ou Oracle) é quase um Pascal, bem facil de converter para PHP, Javascript, etc. Só ter paciência.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz essa implementação simples em uma função de uma linha:

Aqui para telefone de qualquer tipo:

```
function validaTelefone($t){
     return (bool) preg_match('/[0-9]{10,11}/', preg_replace('/\D/', '', $t));
}
```

Aqui apenas para celulares quem tiverem o 9º (nono) dígito preenchido:

```
function validaCelular($c){
     return (bool) preg_match('/[0-9]{2}[9][6789][0-9]{3}[0-9]{4}/', preg_replace('/\D/', '', $c));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use este código que utiliza preg_match para validar e preg_replace para consertar.

```
$validacao = "^\(?(\d{2})\)?\b+(\d{5})\-?(\d{4})$";
if (preg_match($validacao, $telefone)){
    $telefone = preg_replace($validacao, "($1)$2$3", $telefone);
} else {
    //Acao para erro de validacao
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá! Aqui está uma função PHP que resolve o problema da validação de celular e telefone fixo, não importa o formato que o usuário escreva, incluindo a  verificação de que DD e nem número de telefone podem começar com zero..

```
function validarTelefoneCelularEFixo(string $valor): bool {
    
    //processa a string mantendo apenas números no valor de entrada.
    $valor = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $valor); 
        
    $lenValor = strlen($valor);
    
    //validando a quantidade de caracteres de telefone fixo ou celular.
    if($lenValor != 10 && $lenValor != 11)
        return false;
    
    //DD e número de telefone não podem começar com zero.
    if($valor[0] == "0" || $valor[2] == "0")
        return false;
    
    return true;
}

# Testes ------------------------------
    
validarTelefoneCelularEFixo("(11) 99110-0000"); //true
validarTelefoneCelularEFixo("11991100000"); //true
validarTelefoneCelularEFixo("(11)3311-0000"); //true
validarTelefoneCelularEFixo("1133110000"); //true
validarTelefoneCelularEFixo("(00) 99000-0000"); //false
```