# Como criar uma expressão regular para validar apenas numero de celular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

Eu fiz essa expressão, mas não sei se ela está nos padrões de hoje em dia

```
 "/^[1-9]{2}\s?9\s?\d{8}$/"
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/144363/30045

Comment: Teria que ser expressão regular mesmo? Acho que seria mais eficiente colocar uma máscara no campo com jQuery.

Comment: //$regexCel = '/[0-9]{2}[6789][0-9]{3,4}[0-9]{4}/';   https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/144362/como-validar-telefone-em-php

Answer (score 2):

Em relação a pergunta, acho que você deveria ser um pouco mais específico, seu título não condiz com a descrição da pergunta.

**Respondendo ao título:**
Você pode criar uma regex que leia os dígitos separadamente e só dê match caso o número tenha de 8 a 9 dígitos com 2 adicionais para indicar DDD.
Sendo assim você pode usar algo assim:

```
(\({0,1}\d{0,2}\){0,1} {0,1})(\d{4,5}) {0,1}-{0,1}(\d{4})
```

Essa regex identifica se existem separadores como espaço, "-" e "()", como não são atributos obrigatórios ela apenas considera que possam existir e captura do mesmo jeito, aqui tem um [exemplo do funcionamento dela](https://regex101.com/r/xKd38B/1).

**Respondendo a descrição da pergunta:**
Sua regex ainda funciona, está nos padrões de hoje em dia, porém não usaria ela por não considerar os possíveis separadores que podem existir nos campos de telefone, estar presa a possibilidades que devem estar em começo de linhas e aceitar quebras de linhas, tabs e espaços entre partes específicas que podem acabar capturando sequencias de caracteres que não deveriam ser capturadas.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm talvez essa expressão sirva, funcionou para alguns testes com 9 digitos e 8 digitos, com ou sem ddd, e com ou sem hifen

```
var cel = /[0-9]{0,2}?[9]?[0-9]{4}-?[0-9]{4}/;
cel.test('91234-5678') // true
```