# Aplicando mascara Jquery em valor e não input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Olá, tenho os seguintes valores de telefone e celular respectivamente:

Telefone: 1111111111
Celular: 11111111111

Já possuo o valor no banco de dados, gostaria apensar de apresentar esses valores formatados com as seguintes máscaras:

Telefone = (11) 1111-1111
Celular = (11) 11111-1111

Alguém poderia me ajudar ? Gostaria de apenas aplicar as mascaras via JavaScript não quero por no input, pois guardo o valor somente numérico no BD, gostaria apenas de apresenta-lo formatado.

Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço!

Comment: Você pode usar subtring

Comment: Editei minha resposta, por falta de atenção respondi sobre formatação em um input, mas já arrumei para o seu caso, da uma olhada ai! Se puder marcar como resposta correta agradeço ;)

Comment: Um exemplo de como formatar qualquer tipo de padrão de forma flexível com uma única função: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55235/4793

Comment: Bruno, obrigado, mas utilizei a solução do nosso amigo abaixo. Mesmo assim obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **Regex** e **replace():**

```
function mascaraTelefone(value){
    value = value.replace(/\D/g,"");                  //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
    value = value.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/g,"($1) $2"); //Coloca parênteses em volta dos dois primeiros dígitos
    value = value.replace(/(\d)(\d{4})$/,"$1-$2");    //Coloca hífen entre o quarto e o quinto dígitos
    value = value.substr(0, 15);
    return value;
}
```

Chame a função passando o valor (telefone) o retorno dela sera o telefone formatado:

```
//Esse seria o telefone que vem do banco de dados
var tel = "1125346283"

//Essa variavel você pode apresentar
var telFormatado = mascaraTelefone(tel);
```

Comment: Obrigado Lucas! Funcionou corretamente!