# Como formatar resultado com virgula e ponto?

Tags: javascript

Como eu faço para formatar o resultado de uma soma com virgula e ponto.

O Resultado:

```
80.50 *  52 = 4189.00
```

Como pretendo:

```
80.50 *  52 = 4,189.00
```

## Meu JS

```
function calcular() {
 var valores1 = document.getElementsByClassName('txt1');
 var valores2 = document.getElementsByClassName('txt2');
 var resultados = document.getElementsByClassName('result');

 for (let i = 0; i < valores1.length; ++i) {
     let num1 = parseFloat(valores1[i].value);
     let num2 = parseFloat(valores2[i].value);
     resultados[i].value = (num1 * num2).toFixed(2);
 }
}
```

Comment: Já pesquisou aqui no [pt.so]? O que achou?

Comment: o link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55085/como-formatar-um-valor-em-javascript talvez possa ser útil a você.

Comment: O resultado da sua pergunta está errado. rs

Comment: 80.50 * 52 = 4,186.00

Comment: Sim, eu digitei errado hahaha.

Comment: acho que vc não assistiu as aulas de matematica isso sim hahaha

Comment: usei a calculadora pra calcular, pq calcular 80.50 * 52 de cabeça eu nunca iria calcular.

Comment: pois então.nesse dia que vc faltou, o professor ensinou a usar a maquina de calcular kkkk É sempre bom escolher uma resposta como aceita, veja porque aqui  https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resultados[i].value = (((num1 * num2).toFixed(2)).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
```

Exemplo:

```js
function calcular(){
    var valores1 = document.getElementsByClassName('txt1');
    var valores2 = document.getElementsByClassName('txt2');
    var resultados = document.getElementsByClassName('result');

    for (let i = 0; i < valores1.length; ++i){
        let num1 = parseFloat(valores1[i].value);
        let num2 = parseFloat(valores2[i].value);
        //resultados[i].value = (num1 * num2).toFixed(2);
        
       resultados[i].value = (((num1 * num2).toFixed(2)).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
    }
}
```

```html
<input class="txt1" value="80.50" name="opcao1" id="opcao1" type="text">
<input class="txt2" value="52" name="opcao2" id="opcao2" type="text">
<input class="result" value="" name="opcao3" id="opcao3" type="text" onclick="calcular()" placeholder="Clique aqui para calcular">
```

A idéia é combinar recursivamente - com a flag `g` (global) -  fazendo um Lookahead positivo `(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))` - uma sequencia de 3 dígitos `(\d{3})` desde que não haja nenhum digito à direita `(?!\d)` desta sequencia - e que não seja inicio ou fim da cadeia `\B`

**Lookahead** é uma forma de casar strings que tenham ou não um determinado final. É utilizado (?=...) para o positivo, ou seja, que terminem com, e (?!...) para o negativo, ou seja, que não termina com.

Um exemplo simples, seria a busca de Rafael seguido por Ferreira. Se existisse Rafael ou Rafael Outracoisa, ele não casaria. `/Rafael(?= Ferreira)/`

Ao contrário, neste exemplo, somente casaria o Rafael ou o Rafael Outracoisa, porém não casaria o Rafael Ferreira: `/Rafael(?! Ferreira)`

Answer (score 3):

Uma <strike>simples</strike> expressão regular resolve o seu problema:

```
var numero = "4189.00";
numero = numero.replace(/(\d{1,3}|\G\d{3})(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
```

Resultado: `"4,189.00"`

Essa expressão regular funciona para qualquer tamanho de número, com ou sem casas decimais (mas apenas até 3 casas após o ponto).

Comment: Olha, +1, mas "simples" e "expressão regular" na mesma frase é brincadeira.

Comment: Verdade, haha! É que eu já sou acostumado com expressões regulares.

Answer (score 1):

Eu uso o [plugin maskMoney](https://plugins.jquery.com/maskMoney/)

Depois basta você personalizar seu campo com jQuery.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#valor").maskMoney({ thousands: '', decimal: ',', allowZero: true });
  });
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group" id="div_valor">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.valor, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            </div>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.valor, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Existe um método chamado *[toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)*. Este método retorna uma seqüência de caracteres com uma representação sensível ao idioma desse número.

Segundo a documentação a saída *default* do método é padrão americano

```
var number = 3500;
console.log(number.toLocaleString()) //3,500
```

O estranho é que ao testar não é isso que acontece, aplicando o padrão `// 3.500`. Há o padrão alemão que formata valores monetários conforme o Brasil. Para isto acrescente o parâmetro `de-DE` ao método

```
var number = 123456.789;
console.log(number.toLocaleString('de-DE', { maximumFractionDigits: 2 }))
//123.456,79
```